# Need to know how to loop

Tags: python, if-statement

This is my first time asking a question on this site so sorry for the minor mistakes.

The question I have is how do I loop the program back to a previous line. I'll be more specific. In the first else statement I made it so that the program ends. I want it to allow the user to have another try at entering the username. How do I do that?

And If you don't understand then please ask me clarify.

```
usernames = ("Bob","John","Tyler","Thomas","Sanjit",
             "Super_X","Ronald","Royal_X", "Igor","KoolKid")
passwords = ("James","Smith","Jones","password","Desai",
             "asdf123","Roy","King", "Mad_man", "k00lGuy")

username = raw_input("Enter username")

if username == usernames[0] or username == usernames[1] or username == usernames[2] or \
   username == usernames[3] or username == usernames[4] or username == usernames[5] or \
   username == usernames[6] or username == usernames[7] or username == usernames[8] or \
   username == usernames[9]:
    print "  "
else:
    import sys
    sys.exit("This is not a valid username") 

password = raw_input("Enter Password:")

if username == usernames[0] and password == passwords[0] or \
   username == usernames[1] and password == passwords[1] or \
   username == usernames[2] and password == passwords[2] or \
   username == usernames[3] and password == passwords[3] or \
   username == usernames[4] and password == passwords[4] or \
   username == usernames[5] and password == passwords[6] or \
   username == usernames[6] and password == passwords[7] or \
   username == usernames[7] and password == passwords[8] or \
   username == usernames[9] and password == passwords[9]:
       print "log in successful"
else:
    import sys
    sys.exit("Username and Password do not match.")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as follows:

```
username = ''
while username not in usernames:
    username = raw_input('Enter username: ')
```

If you want to give them a certain number of tries, you can do:

```
username = ''
for i in range(3):  #where 3 is the number of tries
    if username not in usernames:
        username = raw_input('Enter username: ')
    else:
        break
```

and then you can do the same thing for passwords. Hope that helps.

Comment: And note the usage of "in" here, which does exactly what you think it would do. It's essentially the short way of writing out the long string of "or's" that you've done a few times

Answer (score 0):

First off, you'd be better off using a `dict` to store username and passwords like this:

```
credentials = {
    "Bob": "James",
     # ....
}
```

If you want to allow the user 2 tries to get the username right:

```
for i in xrange(2):
    username = raw_input('Enter username: ')
    if username in credentials:
        break
else:
    print 'username not valid'
```

The above code uses the `for..else` construct in python to determine if a `break` was used to exit the loop. Now, the dict makes it much easier to check if the password was correct:

```
if password == credentials[username]:
    print 'login successful'
```